# Unmarshal error with golang on AWS Lambda, works locally

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda

I created code in golang that is supposed to support the endpoint API (through get queries). That's documentation of API's endpoint:
https://developer.dotdigital.com/docs/get-all-campaigns

Code looks like this:

```
type Campaign struct {
    Id          int    `json:"id,omitempty"`
    Name        string `json:"name,omitempty"`
    Subject     string `json:"subject,omitempty"`
    FromName    string `json:"fromName,omitempty"`
    FromAddress struct {
        Id    int    `json:"id,omitempty"`
        Email string `json:"email,omitempty"`
    }
    HtmlContent      string `json:"htmlContent,omitempty"`
    PlainTextContent string `json:"plainTextContent,omitempty"`
    ReplyAction      string `json:"replyAction,omitempty"`
    IsSplitTest      bool   `json:"isSplitTest,omitempty"`
    Status           string `json:"status,omitempty"`
}

func (dcfg DotmailerApiConfig) GetContacts2() ([]*dotmailermodels.Contact) {
    var (
        allContacts, respContacts []*dotmailermodels.Contact
        selected                  = 1000
        skip                      = 0
        err error
    )
    for true {
        url := dcfg.Url + fmt.Sprintf("v2/contacts?withFullData=%s&select=%s&skip=%s",
            strconv.FormatBool(false),
            strconv.Itoa(selected),
            strconv.Itoa(skip))
        resp := dcfg.GetRequesDotmailertBuilder(url)
        err = json.Unmarshal(resp, &respContacts)
        if err != nil {
            Error.Println(err) // just error trace
        }
        allContacts = append(allContacts, respContacts...)
        if len(respContacts) == 1000 {
            skip += 1000
            respContacts = nil
            continue
        }
        break
    }
    return allContacts
}
```

When I'm running on my PC I get the correct response. When I use it in Lambda I get this error:

```
[ERROR] 2019/03/24 18:37:26 dotmailergetrequests.go:110: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []*dotmailermodels.Campaign
```

Have you got any idea why?

Comment: The message is stating that the root JSON value is an object, but the application unmarshalling to a slice.  To debug the problem, print the JSON text you are trying to unmarshal.  A random guess is that the API is returning an error instead of what the application is expecting.  Print the HTTP response status code to help debug this possibility.

Comment: but it works perfectly on my PC.

Comment: Yes, something is different between the two environments. It looks like the application is receiving different API responses in the two environments. Printing the HTTP response status code and JSON text in the failing environment may give a hint about what's wrong.

Comment: Not related to your question, but there's no reason to call `strconv.*` for your arguments to `fmt.Sprintf`. Just use the proper formatting verbs--the whole point of Printf/Sprintf is to do that formatting for you.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
type Address struct {
    Id    int    `json:"id,omitempty"`
    Email string `json:"email,omitempty"`
}
type Campaign struct {
    Id          int    `json:"id,omitempty"`
    Name        string `json:"name,omitempty"`
    Subject     string `json:"subject,omitempty"`
    FromName    string `json:"fromName,omitempty"`
    FromAddress *Address `json:"fromAddress,omitempty"`
    HtmlContent      string `json:"htmlContent,omitempty"`
    PlainTextContent string `json:"plainTextContent,omitempty"`
    ReplyAction      string `json:"replyAction,omitempty"`
    IsSplitTest      bool   `json:"isSplitTest,omitempty"`
    Status           string `json:"status,omitempty"`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that error. Everything was correct - except password import in the other file.